# discord.py status in a cog

Tags: python, discord.py

I've searched for this question everywhere but couldn't quite find an answer.

I have just started learning discord.py with very little prior python knowledge so apologies if this question seems very simple, I have been doing this for about 12 hours only using a YouTube tutorial.

So my question is how to have a moving status inside of a cog? I keep getting an error that says "AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'event'".

The cog code is

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from itertools import cycle

status = cycle(['First status', 'Second status', 'Third status'])

class status(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        @tasks.loop(seconds=3)
        async def change_status():
            await commands.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))

        @commands.event
        async def on_ready():
            change_status.start()
            print('Bot ready')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(status(client))
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Here's the final code:

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

class status(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.status = cycle(['First status', 'Second status', 'Third status'])
        print("cog loaded")

    @tasks.loop(seconds=3.0)
    async def change_status(self):
        await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(self.status)))
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        self.change_status.start()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(status(client))
```

There were two things I changed from my previous answer: firstly, the `change_status` and `on_ready` functions needed to be indented backwards to remove them from the indent block of the constructor `class status(commands.Cog)`. This would allow the functions to actually run when the cog was loaded. Secondly, I had to add `await self.client.wait_until_ready()` in the beginning of the `on_ready` function so that the cache is done loading. This should now work as you intended.

Answer (score 3):

After quite a bit of research, I've been able to fix the error that you're getting. However, I've been unable to actually get the statuses to change; this might be because I'm not using the `change_presence()` method correctly. Nevertheless, I can at least help you get rid of the error, and you can take it from there. Below is an amalgamation of the previous mistakes I pointed out in your code, as well as code that will get rid of the error message.

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

class status(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.status = cycle(['First status', 'Second status', 'Third status'])

        @tasks.loop(seconds=3.0)
        async def change_status(self):
            print('Changing status')
            await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(self.status)))
        
        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(self):
            self.change_status.start()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(status(client))
```

What was causing your error was that `@commands.event` doesn't exist. Rather, you would have to use `@commands.Cog.listener()`, which is why the error was showing `'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'event'`. I found a [reddit forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/gxm1az/how_do_i_change_the_status_of_a_discord_bot_using/) talking about the same issue you have, and the person was actually able to fix it, so I'd suggest you read over it and try it out for yourself. I'll delete my older answer, as this one contains everything I pointed out.